# web page display depending on different users

Tags: c#

I have many users. Once the user logs in, he will see a gridview containing documents list in his profile. Say there are two users abc and xyz. abc has documents list like little, tiger, load and xyz has documnets list flower, tiger.  I want to create web page in such a way when abc logs in, his home page's gridview  should contain little, tiger, load and when xyz logs in, his home page's gridview should contain flower, tiger. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to buy a book on ASP.NET and ADO.NET

Comment: This question is very broad and unanswerable in its current form. Do you have a data architecture in mind? What web architecture will you be using i.e. forms, mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx all for ur support. I finally found the solution. In my database table I included one more column named username. When i create any documents i made clear tht i have included the username also to store in the database table. While displaying the gridview which gets the data from the database table, i filtered the data depending on the username like select filename, date  from abc where username = @username. I have added a loginName just above the gridview and stored its value in an invisible lable. I made use of this lable as a control ID in the where clause in the database table. So now whoever logs in, creates the documents, will be able to see only those documents.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Session object.

when user abc loges in - you give him session "a"

when user xyz loges in - you give him session "b"

This is how you should handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which data storage you are using, but the idea is that each document has a property called `UserID` and when a user logs on, you fill the page with all the documents that have their `UserID == LoggedUserID`.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT:**

I assume your users data is stored in a standard .NET user database. If you can't connect the users and documents in the database, you should add a column for storing roles that have access to the documents instead of users. Then each document will have a role who's members are allowed to see the document.

But a better way would be to connect the documents and users with a N:M relation table at database level. Then each document would have a list of users that can see it.

You don't connect the controls with Table1, you check the logged user's username (or some other property) against the Table1's documents. When the user successfully logs in, you can get his username from the `Page` property `User.Identity.Name`. Or if you use roles with documents, you can check if the user is in the document's role with `User.IsInRole("role_name")`

The question is very broad, and it's difficult to give a concrete answer.

Comment: can u tell me bit more in detail. I have only one table called Table1 which has all the documents. I'm using asp.net login controls to create user and login. How can I link my Table1 to these controls?

Comment: In my program, i have a feature in which each user can share his document with other users. If i set the database table such as who all can view which document, then the feature which i told u before will be taken care of?

Comment: @user662417 if by share you mean that some other user can also view the document, then yes. When the user shares, it'll add the other user to the role associated with the document or add a new relation between the document and the other user.

Comment: can u tell me in detail how can I bind the document to the user?

Comment: @user662417 if you are asking about binding the document to the user in the database, ask this in another question. This question as already too vague

Answer (score 0):

You will need a piece of data that links the document to the user. I would suggest grouping the users, and then applying a flag to each document stating whether the document can appear in for a group. This has the advantage that one user can then belong to many groups.

When a user logs in, the session can contain a reference to the group/s they belong to.

Comment: can u tell me how can I do that?

Comment: You will need 3 tables new in your database. One for groups, a second for the relationship between users and group and also a third for the relationship between documents and groups.

You should look into the .net SqlMembershipProvider which will handle most of this for you. However, you will still need to create the 3rd table yourself and the associated functionality.

Comment: can u tell me in detail how can I bind the document to the user?

Comment: If you want to associate a document with a user, you will need a [UserDocuments] table that has at least 2 columns, UserID and DocumentID. You will need some screen for specifying that Documents A and B can be accessed by User 1 etc. This screen will update the [UserDocuments] table by adding in the relevant ID pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list box on the design page and create a List which contains the relevant file name and than simplay bind the list box with the list.

One example can be:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            <StackPanel Margin="0,-21,0,0">
                <ListBox  Height="650" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBoxNews" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="472" ItemsSource="{Binding NewsDetailsCollection}" Foreground="#FF0A0909" FontWeight="Normal"  >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="400" Canvas.Left="50" Height="270" Canvas.Top="6">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <TextBlock Height="38" Name="lblTitle" Width="260" FontSize="28" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" ></Button>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class News : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public News()
        {

            UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder("http://news.google.co.in/news");
            fullUri.Query = "hl=en&gl=in&q=mumbai+marathon&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss";
            HttpWebRequest forecastRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri.Uri);

            ForecastUpdateState forecastState = new ForecastUpdateState();
            forecastState.AsyncRequest = forecastRequest;

            forecastRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandleForecastResponse), forecastState);

            //  wbt.URL = "http://www.google.com";
            //wbt.Show();

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void HandleForecastResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            ForecastUpdateState forecastState = (ForecastUpdateState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebRequest forecastRequest = (HttpWebRequest)forecastState.AsyncRequest;

            forecastState.AsyncResponse = (HttpWebResponse)forecastRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

            Stream streamResult;
            // get the stream containing the response from the async call
            streamResult = forecastState.AsyncResponse.GetResponseStream();
            // load the XML
            XElement xmlNews = XElement.Load(streamResult);
            XElement xmlCurrent = xmlNews.Descendants("channel").First();
            XElement x1 = xmlCurrent.Descendants("item").First();
            string title = (string)x1.Element("title");


            IEnumerable<XElement> xmlIEnumerableNews = xmlCurrent.Descendants("item");

            IEnumerable<NewsDetails> objIEnumerableNews = from element in xmlIEnumerableNews
                                                          select new NewsDetails
                                                          {
                                                              title = (string)(element.Element("title")),
                                                              link = (string)(element.Element("guid")),
                                                              date = (string)(element.Element("pubDate"))
                                                          };


            List<NewsDetails> objListNews = new List<NewsDetails>();
            int count = objListNews.Count;
            foreach (NewsDetails news in objIEnumerableNews)
            {
                news.title = news.title + " " + news.date;
                int pos = news.link.IndexOf('=');
                news.link = news.link.Substring(pos + 1, news.link.Length - pos - 1);
                objListNews.Add(news);
            }

            int t = objListNews.Count();
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                listBoxNews.ItemsSource = objListNews;
            });
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewsDetails news = (sender as Button).DataContext as NewsDetails;
            WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
            wbt.URL = news.link;
            wbt.Show();

        }

        private void FAQs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Info/FAQs/Questions.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

        private void Weather_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Info/Weather.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

        private void About_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Info/About.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

    }
    public class NewsDetails
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        //public String title, link, description;
    }
```

please be specific on what are your working languages

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge question that really can't be answered within the scope of a qustion on stack overflow.  If this is for something like "i need a website that does this right now" and you are asking this question your best bet is to look at some existing CMSs and see what they can do for you out of the box.

If they meet your needs cool, otherwise as Hasan says you are probably going to need to buy a book and start learning to build websites.  Again starting with an existing CMS is probably a good approach.

Although I hesitate to mention it for fear that you will just dive into a problem you aren't ready for... [OrchardCMS](http://orchardproject.net/) will let you build this kind of page without writing too much code (though not zero and you will still need to know your way around C#, razor, and ASP.NET), without having to dig into the database stuff too much, and is open source which gives you a good repository of code that does things similar to what you want to do.